# How to translate a custom user role name?

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I've added a few custom user roles with english names. I need to translate them to other languages now. What is the best way to do this?

According to the [user_roles](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/7) function only "core provided" role names can be translated by default.

I've installed the [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) module and fiddled around but haven't found the correct way yet.

Comment: This is an so far unresolved core issue. Lingering since 2009. See: https://www.drupal.org/node/598862